# Incorrect distance travelled using optical wheel encoder

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, robotics, encoder

I started using a raspberry pi 3b+ about 2 months ago, so I'm fairly new. I'm working on a project, in which I have assembled a 4 wheeled small car, it has 4 DC motors, a 3b+, an L289D H bridge and an optical wheel encoder.

I'm in my initial stages of the project where I am testing the kit, whether it travels the correct distance or not. Below is the code that I'm using to test the process:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)   #clockwise left
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)   #anticlockwise right
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)   #anticlockwise left
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)   #clockwise right

stateLast = GPIO.input(11)
rotationCount=0
stateCount=0
stateCountTotal=0
flag=0

circ=62.4*3.14 #mm
statesPerRotation=20
distancePerStep= circ/statesPerRotation

GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
flag="true"
while flag=="true":
    stateCurrent = GPIO.input(11)
    if stateCurrent != stateLast:
        stateLast = stateCurrent
        stateCount += 1
        stateCountTotal += 1
        
    if stateCount == statesPerRotation:
        rotationCount += 1
        stateCount = 0
        
    distance = distancePerStep * stateCountTotal
    print("Distance",distance)
    if distance > 50:
        flag = "false"

GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
```

What's happening is that upon running the code, the kit is not travelling the distance I enter in the code above. When I use lower values of distance, the kit travels accurately, but as soon as I increase the distance to greater than 200mm for example, the kit falls short of the actual distance it is supposed to travel. For 300mm, it stops at around 250mm on ground, but the interesting thing is that upon printing the distance from the code, it runs till 300mm. I am failing to understand that why is the code showing that the kit has travelled 300mm but in reality it always stops at around 220mm-250mm.

Another interesting thing I've noticed is that when I use Thonny to run the code, the distance travelled is always inconsistent, no matter the value of distance. For example, if I use distance 20mm, sometimes it ran 10mm, at other moments 30mm, and never accurate. When I ran the code.py file from the terminal, the distance it travelled became consistent, but still inaccurate as stated in the above paragraph.

I'm using remote desktop connection to access the 3b+. I have used another wheel encoder to ensure there's no problem with it and have also checked the battery voltage, which is good. Other than that I have tested the kit on different surfaces as well, but nothing has worked till now.

I would appreciate if anyone helps me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the optical switch is "bouncing" which makes your counts high. (Certainly mechanical switches do this.) Try putting a small delay in your loop after it detects a transition and see if that helps. Don't pick too high a delay or you'll miss the next "real" one!

Comment: Yes, you need to understand what the actual frequency of the optical encoder is. You should match the sampling by your code to slightly greater than twice that frequency.

Comment: We have counted/displayed the number of steps as well and it precisely counts that but there is still a discrepancy between the distance covered and what is expected.

Comment: The code manages real-time activity. In real-time programming, code must be careful of blocking issues. (remember, python is single-threaded because of the GIL). For instance, in the while loop `print("Distance",distance)` is blocking. There may be other issues. One reason I suspect blocking is that the problem is worse in Thonny. Thonny is more affected by blocking statements. Start by threading the print statement?

Comment: Its possible that the steps you are recording are simply 'noise' from the optical encoder.

Comment: @quamrana if the issue is indeed noise, how can I eliminate it?

Comment: Could you record an exact time for each transition? Eg. create `records = []` and then at each transition detected add: `records.append(datetime.datetime.now())`. When I get thonny to run a fast loop I get times that are 1 millisecond apart.

Comment: Perhaps a better clock is: `records.append(time.perf_counter())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# real-time processing requires fast non blocking code. Try the following 
# and see if the performance improves.
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)  # clockwise left
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)  # anticlockwise right
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)  # anticlockwise left
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)  # clockwise right

stateLast = GPIO.input(11)
rotationCount = 0
stateCount = 0
stateCountTotal = 0
flag = 0

circ = 62.4 * 3.14  # mm
statesPerRotation = 20
distancePerStep = circ / statesPerRotation

GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
# flag = "true"

while True: # Use boolean logic not string evaluation
    stateCurrent = GPIO.input(11)
    if stateCurrent != stateLast:
        stateLast = stateCurrent
        stateCount += 1
        stateCountTotal += 1

    if stateCount == statesPerRotation:
        rotationCount += 1
        stateCount = 0

    distance = distancePerStep * stateCountTotal
    # print("Distance", distance)  # Do not print in th e loop
    if distance > 50:
        break
print("Distance", distance)
GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
```